# import only specific package from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a python package defined via `__init__.py` in a folder named `python_utils` that has many python scripts in it.

```
 python_utils/
     __init__.py
     print_pretty.py
     script_1.py
     ...
```

For convenience this `__init__.py` imports all of them using:

```
from .pretty_print import pretty_print
from .scritp_1 import func1
from .script_2 import func2
....
```

The problem I have is that some of the python scripts depend on packages that may not be available at run time. So when I try to import a very trivial function from the package (`from python_utils import print_pretty`), it fails because of the dependencies the other scripts have. I also tried to import directly with `from python_utils.print_pretty import print_pretty` same problem. I can get rid of the `__init__.py` to solve the problem, but it saves me a lot of typing when importing packages. Is there a way I can import only `pretty_print` without getting the dependencies from the other scripts?

Comment: What is the content of `__init__.py`?

Comment: The only statements it has are from statements like: `from .pretty_print import pretty_print` etc.

Comment: Why would the depends from the other scripts fail? Can you `try/except` it out? Also, there's probably some design principle somewhere that says that if they're separate, they should be in different packages.

Comment: For example one script depends on python crontab package that I do not have. I guess I can group them in two or more folders and add two more `__init__.py`s to import them separately.

Comment: Why not install crontab? Is there a reason to specifically not have the depends? I still stand by my idea to make them into separate packages if they don't have any functionalities that depend on each other.

Comment: It is a complicated workflow where a certain conda environment is activated depending on the situation. I should not have said I don't have crontab package, it is just in another environment where it is really needed. Anyway, I am asking here hoping there is some magic that can be done in `__init__.py` if not I will find other ways ...

Comment: I suppose using `__all__` can work, and importing each of the individual things with try/except in case the crontab fails.

Comment: Thanks, I will try/except, that might actually work!